# Change background color based on updated record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails application with upvoting and downvoting functionality.  I want the color to change to green if upvotes are > 0 and change to red if downvotes are > 0.   I have a helper that renders the page like this but I'd like it to update on the users screen without a page refresh.

index.html.erb

```
<div class="panel-left">
  <%= link_to 'Upvote', upvote_post_path(post), method: :patch, remote: true  %>
  <br />
  <%= link_to 'Downvote', downvote_post_path(post), method: :patch, remote: true %>

  <h1 class="<%=number_of_votes(post.vote_count) %>">
    <div id="total-votes-<%= post.id %>">
      <%= post.vote_count %>
    </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

upvote.js.erb:

```
// this updates the counter: it works
$("#total-votes-<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= @post.vote_count %>")

//this is what I am not sure of, I hacked it together but it breaks everything (prevents the above from updating) and shows a server error in the console
if($('<%= escape_javascript @post.vote_count) %>') > 0) {
  $("<%=escape_javascript number_of_votes(post.vote_count) %>").attr('style', 'background-color: rgb(179, 144, 114)');
} else {
  $("<%= escape_javascript number_of_votes(post.vote_count) %>").attr('style', 'background-color: rgb(115, 227, 87)');
};
```

posts helper

```
module PostsHelper
  def number_of_votes(votes)
    if votes > 0
      'positive-bg'
    elsif votes < 0
      'negative-bg'
    end
  end
end
```

As I said everything works fine except I want the background to change colors if the users' vote is enough to change `@post.vote_count` to greater than or less than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the `class` in `h1` tag, so just add an `id` to it (in the same way you are adding one to its child `div`) and update that element's `class` in the `js.erb` file.

**index.html.erb**

```ruby
<div class="panel-left">
  <%= link_to 'Upvote', upvote_post_path(post), method: :patch, remote: true %>
  <br />
  <%= link_to 'Downvote', downvote_post_path(post), method: :patch, remote: true %>

  <h1 id="vote-<%= post.id %>" class="<%=number_of_votes(post.vote_count) %>">
    <div id="total-votes-<%= post.id %>">
      <%= post.vote_count %>
    </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Notice the addition of `id="vote-<%= post.id %>"`; that `id` will be identify the element and change its `class`.

**upvote.js.erb**

```
$("#total-votes-<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= @post.vote_count %>")
$("#vote-<%= @post.id %>").attr("class", "<%= number_of_votes(@post.vote_count) %>");
```

So you will use the `id` of `h1` tag to update its `class` the same way you assign it in the first place (i.e. using `number_of_votes` helper).

Comment: You're a genius!